# Apex trigger to redirect to child object once the parent is created

Tags: trigger

Hi developer community,

I have the following trigger creating a child object when parent is saved. However, not all the field on the child object gets populated because they are only available on the child record.

```
trigger CreateBuyingInfluence on Opportunity_Positioning__c (after insert)

{
   List<Buying_Influence__c> Childs = new List<Buying_Influence__c>();
   for(Opportunity_Positioning__c a : trigger.new)
   {
      Buying_Influence__c Child = new Buying_Influence__c ();
      Child.SCOP__c = a.id;
      Child.Name = 'testName'; 

      Childs.add(Child);      
   }

   insert Childs;
}
```

So, I'm now trying to create a trigger that redirects me to the child page once parent is created/record saved.

When the Parent object=Opportunity Positioning is created then upon saving the record a trigger will prompt me to create Child Object=Buying Influences.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thank you so much. Rog

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is only meant to function at database level. It can't influence the UI and forward a user to a new page.

You have the following alternatives:

1. create a formula field on the parent object containing a 'reminder' to create the child
2. create all child fields in the parent object and copy them over from there in your trigger
3. create 1 visualforce page overriding the parent new/edit page and make sure both objects are created from that page.
4. create a visual workflow that takes the user through the process of creating the 2 objects

I'd suggest to go for #3 if you have the knowledge of APEX/Visualforce.

Comment: Hi Guy, thank you for your response. I have considered alternatives 2 and 3.

Comment: I've even started to work on a APEX/Visualforce page, however, as my knowledge was very limited I couldn't make it work.  How would the option 1 work? Could I use it as a pop up?

Comment: Not as a popup, but you could use a roll-up summary to check whether or not the parent has a child or not. Based on that, show anything (colored text, whatever) in the formula field that you'll put on top of the page.

Comment: Since you're not that experienced in APEX/Visualforce, I've added an option #4 that should be a bit easier to do.

Comment: I've tried creating a Flow as well, but from a UI perspective, my managers didn't like how the data was displaying in only one column.

Comment: I see.. If the formula-field solution is not enough, maybe you could put whatever you have in Visualforce/APEX in a separate question and ask for help here. Or alternatively take some basic visualforce courses online. That should get you there.